# We have to maximize the modulo function

Tags: c++, arrays, max, modulo

In this question we have to maximize the modulo function. A string is given And we have remove the element and check after removing a element which number give the maximum modulo answer.

Link:- https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/maximize-modulo-2-0cb15ded/

My code is not able to pass all test case it shows runtime error or wrong answer in most test case.

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;
 
int countDigit(long long n)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
 
int main() {
 
    int t;
    cin>>t;
 
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        int m,k;
        cin>>m>>k;
 
        string s;
        cin>>s;
 
        int ans = INT_MIN;
 
        int n = countDigit(k);
 
        if(n == m && stoi(s) < k){
            cout<<stoi(s)<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        else{
 
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            string a = "";
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
                if(j == i){
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    a += s[j];
                }
            }
 
            int mo;
            int num = stoi(a);
            mo = num%k;
 
            if(mo > ans){
                ans = mo;
            }
 
        }
 
        cout<<ans<<endl;
 
        }
 
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me where i'm making the mistake or please tell me any better way to solve this question?

Comment: Suggestion: Don't count digits in numbers. Instead count digits in strings. It's a lot easier to do `str.size()` and then convert `str` to a number than all the work in `countDigit`. In general, do as much digit manipulation as possible with strings.

Comment: Suggestion: try to harvest the test case your code fails. It's always easier to debug with a known failure case than without.

Comment: I have used s[i] - '0' to convert it to integer  and also tried to harvest some test case and correct my code but it doesn't help. In every new test case it is showing some error and if we try to add all correction after seeing the test case it will make the code large. @user4581301